# How I can to insert emoji smile to faq microdata in ld+json?

Tags: emoji, schema.org, microdata, json-ld

I have a `faq` microdata in `ld+json` format:

```
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "FAQPage",
  "mainEntity": [
    {
      "@type": "Question",
      "name": "What should my {{ profession.name|lower }} cover letter contain?",
      "acceptedAnswer": {
        "@type": "Answer",
        "text": "The main purpose of a cover letter is to introduce yourself, mention the job you’re applying for, show that your skills and experience match the needed skills and experience for the job."
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I insert this emoji smile `&#128196;` to `name` field and how I can to test it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set it to the name. You can test your structured data with the [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool).

```
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "FAQPage",
  "mainEntity": [
    {
      "@type": "Question",
      "name": "What should my {{ profession.name|lower }} cover letter contain? &#128196;",
      "acceptedAnswer": {
        "@type": "Answer",
        "text": "The main purpose of a cover letter is to introduce yourself, mention the job you’re applying for, show that your skills and experience match the needed skills and experience for the job."
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Can I somehow make all browsers display the same emoji?**

You can't since every provider can show the emoji as a different image. The unicode character of the emoji will be translated into an image. You can also see the differences in [this Unicode Emoji Chart](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html). The emojis can also look different on devices.

Comment: Can I somehow make all browsers display the same emoji?

Comment: No, because Emoji is not an image, it is a font.